# Execute a php file from a php function

Tags: php, function, call, system, passthru

I'm stuck in a very big problem.

Inside my website I call this function, for execute this file called "sched.php"

```
function write()

    passthru('php /var/www/html/sched.php',$err);
    return $err;
}
```

But nothing is done. 
It's my output:

```
<output of sched.php>

1
```

I'don't understand, where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 include "sched.php";  //plus the path, if needed
 return $err;
```

Comment: same thing, Error. Nothin is changed.
Maybe something is wrong with my apache configuation? 
Where can I check ?